# Script para cálculo de desconto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tem um *plugin* de a agência criou.

Ele funciona assim, ela ta setada para funcionar com a palavra boleto e desconto, se tiver esses nomes na classe da `div` ele pega o valor em % ele aplica um display block e aplica no preço a vista.

Ex: `<p style="display:inline-block" class="flag desconto-5--a-vista qd_sp_on">Desconto 5% à vista</p>`

o que eu precisava é que tivesse mais um `IF` que ele funcionasse com a palavra Parcelado e Black.

http://jsfiddle.net/u78wg12e/

```js
'function' !== typeof String.prototype.trim && (String.prototype.trim = function() {
  return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
});
(function(t) {
  var d = jQuery,
    p,
    q,
    b,
    r,
    l;
  'function' !== typeof d.fn.QD_SmartPrice && (q = function(a, b) {
    if ('object' === typeof console) {
      var d = 'object' === typeof a;
      'undefined' !== typeof b && 'alerta' === b.toLowerCase() ? d ? console.warn('[Smart Price]\n', a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7]) : console.warn('[Smart Price]\n' + a) : 'undefined' !== typeof b && 'info' === b.toLowerCase() ? d ? console.info('[Smart Price]\n', a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7]) : console.info('[Smart Price]\n' + a) : d ? console.error('[Smart Price]\n', a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7]) : console.error('[Smart Price]\n' + a)
    }
  }, r = {
    isDiscountFlag: function(a) {
      return -1 < a.text().search(/[0-9]+\%/i) ? !0 : !1
    },
    getDiscountValue: function(a) {
      return a.text().match(/[0-9]+(?=\%)/i)
    },
    getDiscountValueNew: function(a) {
      return a.text().match(/[0-9,]+(?=\%)/i)
    },
    isProductPage: 'auto',
    changeNativePrice: !0,
    changeNativeSaveAmount: !0,
    wrapperElement: 'li',
    wrapperElementProductPage: '.productRightColumn',
    filterFlagBy: '[class*=\'desconto\']',
    forcePromotion: null,
    appliedDiscount: null,
    oneFlagByItem: !0
  }, p = function(a) {
    var n = function(a) {
      var b = {
        jjj: '%25C2%25A8ef1%25C2%25A8pbz%25C2%25A8oe',
        'ef1%25C': '2%25A8pbz%25C2%25A8oe',
        'jj2%25C2%25': 'A8ef1%25C2%25A8pbz%25C2%25A8oe',
        'qrirybc-ef1%25C': '2%25A8igrkpbzzreprfgnoyr%25C2%25A8pbz%25C2%25A8oe',
        'qrirybc-ef1%25C2%25': 'A8igrkpbzzreprorgn%25C2%25A8pbz%25C2%25A8oe',
        'qrirybc-ef1%25C2%25A8ig': 'rkpbzzrepr%25C2%25A8pbz%25C2%25A8oe',
        'ef1%25C2%25A8igrkpbzzreprfg': 'noyr%25C2%25A8pbz%25C2%25A8oe',
        'ef1%25C2%25A8igrkpbzzreprorgn%2': '5C2%25A8pbz%25C2%25A8oe',
        'ef1%25C2%25A8igrkpbzzrepr%25C2%25A8': 'pbz%25C2%25A8oe',
        'jjj%25C2%25A8ef1%25C2%25A8igrkpbzzrepr%': '25C2%25A8pbz%25C2%25A8oe'
      };
      return function(a) {
        var k,
          c,
          d,
          f;
        k = function(a) {
          return a
        };
        c = [
          'a',
          'e',
          18,
          'm',
          's',
          'k',
          'd',
          'u',
          'g',
          'h',
          'a',
          'g',
          's',
          't',
          'z',
          'y',
          'o',
          'u',
          'o'
        ];
        d = a['d' + c[16] + 'c' + c[17] + 'm' + k(c[1]) + 'n' + c[13]]['l' + c[18] + 'c' + c[0] + 'ti' + k('o') + 'n'];
        a = function(a) {
          return escape(encodeURIComponent(a.replace(/\./g, '¨').replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function(a) {
            return String.fromCharCode(('Z' >= a ? 90 : 122) >= (a = a.charCodeAt(0) + 13) ? a : a - 26)
          })))
        };
        for (var l in b) {
          if (a(d[[c[9],
            k('o'),
            c[12],
            c[k(13)]
          ].join('')]) === l + b[l]) {
            f = 'tr' + c[17] + 'e';
            break
          }
          f = 'f' + c[0] + 'ls' + k(c[1]) + ''
        }
        return f
      }(a)
    }(t);
    if (eval(n)) {
      var s = function(a) {
        var e,
          g,
          h,
          c,
          m,
          f,
          n;
        e = d(this);
        if (('undefined' === typeof a ? 0 : a) || e.is(b.filterFlagBy)) {
          if (a = e.getParent(b.wrapperElement + ', ' + b.wrapperElementProductPage), f = !1, b.isProductPage && a.is(b.wrapperElementProductPage) && (f = !0), !e.is('.qd_sp_on, .qd_sp_ignored') || f) {
            if (f) {
              m = a.find('strong.skuBestPrice');
              if (m.find('.qd_active').length) return;
              m.removeClass('qd-active')
            }
            if (b.oneFlagByItem && e.siblings('.qd_sp_on').length) e.addClass('qd_sp_ignored');
            else if (e.addClass('qd_sp_on'), b.isDiscountFlag(e)) {
              var xy;
              g = b.getDiscountValue(e);
              g = parseFloat(g, 10);
              xy = b.getDiscountValueNew(e);
              xy = xy + '';
              g = parseFloat(xy.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'), 10);
              if (isNaN(g)) return q(['O valor informado p/ o desconto não é um número.',
                e
              ], 'alerta');
              e = a.find('.qd_productPrice');
              h = f ? m.text().trim() : e.val() || '';
              h = parseFloat(h.replace(/[^0-9\.\,]+/i, '').replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'), 10);
              isNaN(h) && (h = 0.001);
              null !== b.appliedDiscount && (c = 0, isNaN(b.appliedDiscount) ? (n = a.find(b.appliedDiscount), n.length && (c = b.getDiscountValue(n))) : c = b.appliedDiscount, c = parseFloat(c, 10), isNaN(c) && (c = 0), 0 !== c && (h = 100 * h / (100 - c)));
              c = f ? a.find('strong.skuListPrice').text().trim() : a.find('.qd_productOldPrice').val() || '';
              c = parseFloat(c.replace(/[^0-9\.\,]+/i, '').replace('.', '').replace(',', '.'), 10);
              isNaN(c) && (c = 0.001);
              g = (100 - g) / 100 * h;
              f && b.changeNativePrice ? m.text(m.text().trim().replace(/[0-9\.]+\,[0-9]+/, l(g))).addClass('qd-active') : a.find('.qd_displayPrice').append(l(g));
              f && (h = d('<input type="hidden" class="qd_active" />'), m.append(h), h.bind('destroyed', function() {
                m.removeClass('qd-active')
              }));
              a.find('.qd_saveAmount').append(l(c - g));
              a.find('.qd_saveAmountPercent').prepend(l(100 * (c - g) / c));
              f && b.changeNativeSaveAmount && (f = d('em.economia-de'), f.text(f.text().trim().replace(/[0-9\.]+\,[0-9]+/, l(c - g))), f.addClass('qd-active'));
              a.addClass('qd_sp_processedItem');
              e.addClass('qd_sp_processedItem')
            }
          }
        } else a = e.getParent(b.wrapperElement + ', ' + b.wrapperElementProductPage),
          b.isProductPage && a.is(b.wrapperElementProductPage) && a.find('strong.skuBestPrice').addClass('qd-active')
      };
      a.each(function() {
        s.call(this, !1)
      });
      'string' === typeof b.forcePromotion && a.getParent(b.wrapperElement + ', ' + b.wrapperElementProductPage).find('.qd_productPrice:not(.qd_sp_processedItem)').each(function() {
        var a = d(b.forcePromotion);
        a.attr('style', 'display:none !important;');
        d(this).after(a);
        s.call(a, !0)
      })
    }
  }, l = function(a) {
    var b = '',
      d = '',
      k = 0,
      e;
    a = a.toFixed(2).split('.');
    for (var g = e = a[0].length; 0 < g; g--) b = a[0].substr(g - 1, 1),
      k++,
      0 === k % 3 && e > k && (b = '.' + b),
      d = b + d;
    return d + ',' + a[1]
  }, d.fn.QD_SmartPrice = function(a) {
    b = d.extend({}, r, a);
    'boolean' !== typeof b.isProductPage && (b.isProductPage = d('body').is('.produto'));
    p(d(this))
  })
})(this);;

smartPrice: function() {
  // Verificando se é página de KIT
  var wrapperElementProductPage = $('body').is('.produtoKit') ? '.skuSelect' : '.productRightColumn';
  // Percorrendo cada item afim de identificar qual regra deve ser considerada
  $('.sp-collection:not(.qd_sp_processedItem), .shelf li:not(.qd_sp_processedItem), .productRightColumn').each(function() {
    var flag = $(this).find('p.flag');
    if (flag.filter('[class*=\'boleto\']').length) {
      flag.QD_SmartPrice({
        filterFlagBy: '[class*=\'boleto\']',
        appliedDiscount: '[class*=\'parcelado\']',
        forcePromotion: '<p class="flag desconto-a-vista-0-">desconto 0%</p>',
        wrapperElement: 'li, .sp-collection',
        wrapperElementProductPage: wrapperElementProductPage
      });
      flag.not('[class*="desconto"]').attr('style', 'display:inline-block');
      /*Usado inline-block para seguir o CSS já está existente no common*/
    } else {
      flag.QD_SmartPrice({
        filterFlagBy: '[class*=\'desconto\']',
        forcePromotion: '<p class="flag desconto-a-vista-0-">desconto 0%</p>',
        wrapperElement: 'li, .sp-collection',
        wrapperElementProductPage: wrapperElementProductPage
      });
      flag.attr('style', 'display:inline-block');
      /*Usado inline-block para seguir o CSS já existente no common*/
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thiago, bem vindo ao SOpt. Qual o problema com o código? Por que você não está conseguindo fazer a alteração?

Comment: Colocar código comprimido aqui dificulta muito alguém ter o tempo necessário para o ajudar no seu problema...

Comment: Eu não manjo JS então para fazer isso ai não consigo entender o funcionamento, o que eu sei é que precisaria de 2 else if para que quando tivesse a palavra parcelado ou black entende?

Comment: E esse é o único código que tenho, não tenho versão desenvolvimento.

Comment: Tenta colocar o seu código no site http://jsfiddle.net/, ajuda a gente te ajudar.

Comment: É meio arriscado editar código gerado por computador como esse. Se alguém atualizar a versão original a nova versão do código minificado não vai ter as suas modificações.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que a lógica está no lugar errado. Aplicar o desconto na exibição do boleto, via javascript não é o ideal, porque você não tem o valor final no servidor. O ideal é que no script do servidor rastrear a opção de pagamento do cliente e gerar o boleto já no valor certo, em vez de gerar um boleto padrão e alterar via javascript. Se for isto, acho melhor reescrever tudo no servidor a tentar manter o código legado.
Seu servidor é PHP, ASP, Python, o que? Às vezes é até Node.js e eu estou falando besteira.

Comment: Isso é só visual mesmo, é que a promoção que ta a % funciona só no checkout no pagamento boleto na exibição de produto ele não aparece o valor com % de desconto, ai pra isso existe o plugin.